# On Illustrator I have a white fill on my line segment that appears when I use the zig zag effect on it

Tags: adobe-illustrator

This is for Adobe Illustrator. I am a beginner and am following a YouTube tutorial and they want us to start will a line segment. Once I add the Zig Zag effect on the line segment it ends up with filler in between the waves. This has happened previously and Im not sure how to fix or avoid this from happening. Any tips? [image: Its like a line running straight through the object from one end to the other]

Answer (score 1):

There's a **Fill** applied to the path.

Remove the fill via the **Color, Appearance, or Property Panels**.

By default, Illustrator draws all new objects with a white fill and black stroke. On straight paths, the fill is never really *visible*, nonetheless it's still there. As soon as the path is no longer straight, you see the fill.

Comment: OHHHH thank you very much

Comment: @Lily - if this answer solved your problem, don't forget to accept it as the best answer.